# What is the amount of memory used by Javascript arrays?

Tags: javascript, function

What is the amount of memory used by JavaScript arrays? For example, how can I calculate the required memory for this?

```
var arr = [];
for (var y=0; y<10000; ++y){
    arr[y] = [];
    for (var x=0; x<10000; ++x)
        arr[y][x] = []; 
}
```

Comment: You're missing some `{}`, the loop over `x` will not work as you expect it to.

Comment: That's dependent upon the JS engine. Aside from that, I don't think you can.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Memory_Management